# Long term behavior of a nonlinear dynamic system

Tags: recurrence-relations, finite-differences, stability-theory, nonlinear-dynamics

Consider the following system of first order nonlinear difference equation:
$$
\begin{cases}
x_{k+1} = x_k + \alpha(1-x_ky_k^2) \\
y_{k+1} = y_k + \alpha(1-x_k^2y_k) \\
\end{cases}
$$
with a given initial condition $x_0>y_0$. How to show that if we fix a small enough constant $\alpha>0$, then $(x_k,y_k)_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$ is a bounded sequence?

---

Notice that numerical experiments show that the bound of this sequence may get larger and larger if we take $\alpha$ smaller and smaller, but as long as $\alpha$ is a small enough constant, neither $|x_k|$ nor $|y_k|$ will go to infinity as $k\to\infty$.

---

I don't know what is the standard approach to analyze such kind of nonlinear difference equation without Lipschitz continuous gradient. I would appreciate it if one can provide some possible approaches that I can have a try.

Comment: what happens in the continuum limit?

Comment: @user619894 In the continuous limit, if you initialize at any point $x_0\ne y_0$, the solution to the corresponding ode satisfies $|x(t)|+|y(t)|\to\infty$ as $t\to\infty$.

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/429676/unbounded-solution-but-bounded-euler-discretization/429924?noredirect=1#comment1107261_429924 provides a good view of this question.